# Invoking a component method from another component in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have 3 classes named : Main, Menu, Area as Vue objects and in html they are designed like below

```
<div>
    <main>
         <menu :area="area"></menu>
         <area></area>
    </main>
<div>
```

As described above menu component is using area component as a prop and some functions are working in menu component to change something in area component. I assigned area property like below in main class

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Area from "./area.vue";
import Menu from "./menu.vue";

@Component({
    components: {
        Menu,
        Area
    }
})
export default class Main extends Vue {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.area= new Area();
    }
    area: area;
}
```

However, when i clicked a button in menu it should change a property of area component (it is changing actually) on html. Maybe because of instantiating area inside constructor is creating two different instances and that is the answer. But i dont't know how to use them as single objects

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, because of some code that is missing.
But usually, when you communicate with a parent component, this is done with `events` and you shouldn't manipulate parent's object state directly. See [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). When you have a `non-Parent-Child Communication` you should use a simple Vue instance as a `Bus`.